# Mapping Dataflows time column to Sql time column

Tags: sqldatatypes, azure-data-factory

SQL server db has a time column datatype of

> [start_time] time NULL,
> [end_time] time NULL,

but dataflows doesn't have a function for this.
The only way I can think of doing this is a post query (if you fully recreate the table)

```
  alter table dbo.[testTable] 
  alter column [start_time] time(0) 
  alter column [end_time] time(0)
```

I tried using timestamp but again it's not a matching datatype

> toTimestamp(substring(start_date,12,9),'HH:mm:ss')

so this doesn't work.

Any help on understanding this would be great

** updating with screens shots
So this issue is for parquet or csv to Sql db tables.

if you have a column that looks like DateTime you need to keep it as a string as there is no toDateTime function only toTimestamp. Neither string or Timestamp can be converted to DateTime datatype in SQLdb sink. You will end up with nulls in your column

[image]
[image]
[image]

Sample befor using expression to change the start_date to yyyy-mm-dd THH:mm:ss

> [image: Blockquote]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply map the DATETIME column to the target TIME column in the sink activity.

[image]

Make sure the option "Allow schema drift" in sink activity is unchecked.

[image: Make sure the option "Allow schema drift" is unchecked]

My test schema:

```
-- source table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[tempSourceTable]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tempSourceTable](
    [id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [key] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [start_date] datetime NULL
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[tempSourceTable] VALUES ('key1', '2021-10-14 12:34:56')

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tempSourceTable]

-- target table

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[tempTargetTable]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tempTargetTable](
    [id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [key] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [start_time] time NULL
)
```

result after execute the dataflow in a pipeline:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the prompt response and I see what you have done here which is correct. 
Does this only work with dataflow database table to table? 
Example:- my column start_date is in a  .csv string format '04/10/2021 11:30:53' you cannot simply set that to date as it will be truncated down to the date and will show null anything else.

Comment: Would be great if you can provide the sample CSV so we can look deeper into that to see what we can help :)

Comment: Done. :-) Please see my edited post.
 thank you for your help. Ideally just being able to have a datetime column in a file and load to SQL DateTime is the ideal scenario

Comment: I have added another answer using your sample CSV as input. If the new answer is what you are looking for, I will delete this old answer and only keep the new one. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my testing CSV input:

```
start_date,end_date,start_date_time,end_date_time,start_time,end_time
09/01/2020,09/01/2020,09/01/2020 11:01,09/01/2020 11:01,11:01:46,11:01:52
09/01/2020,,09/01/2020 11:01,,11:01:47,
09/01/2020,09/01/2020,09/01/2020 11:01,09/01/2020 11:50,11:01:49,11:50:41
09/01/2020,09/01/2020,09/01/2020 11:01,09/01/2020 11:01,11:01:51,11:01:55
09/01/2020,09/01/2020,09/01/2020 11:01,09/01/2020 11:01,11:01:52,11:01:56
```

You may specify the data/time/datetime format for CSV source data:
[image]

You can see the correct parsing result in data preview:
[image]

After that, a simple sink activity should achieve what OP wants to do:
[image]

The sink table schema I used for testing:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tempTargetTable](
    [start_date] date NULL,
    [end_date] date NULL,
    [start_date_time] datetime NULL,
    [end_date_time] datetime NULL,
    [start_time] time NULL,
    [end_time] time NULL
)
```

Result in DB:
[image]